# Configuring quote environment for bilingual writing

Tags: xetex, environments, languages, books, quotation

I am trying to configure a bilingual (Bangla+English) quote environment in book class. For the following MWE, I am using these fonts:

1. Kalpurush [(download source)](https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html)
2. My Type Of Font [(download source)](https://www.1001freefonts.com/my-type-of-font.font)

(The second one can be replaced with any familiar English font.)

### test_quote.sty

```
\RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,   % Kalpurush font: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html 
                banglattfont=Kalpurush,
               ]{latexbangla}
%activate polyglossia
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
%number all levels
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%     \setotherlanguage{english}

% new font for quotation
\newfontfamily\quotefont[%
    % Scale= 1.1,
    % WordSpace=1.4,
    % AutoFakeSlant=1.2,
    % AutoFakeBold=1.2
    ]{[mytype]}  % My Type Of Font font: https://www.1001freefonts.com/my-type-of-font.font 

% A chapquote environment for chapter quotes
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
{\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
    \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
    \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
    \uccoff \quotefont 
}
{\par\hfill \uccoff — \uccon \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
```

### test_quote.tex

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{test_quote}

\begin{document}

আমার পছন্দের একটা উক্তি হলঃ \\

\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
    One glance at a book and you hear the voice of another person, perhaps someone dead for 1000 years. To read is to voyage through time.
\end{chapquote}

\vspace{4em}
এটার বাংলা অনুবাদ করলে দাঁড়ায় এমনঃ \\

\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
    একটি বইয়ের পাতায় এক নজর তাকালে আপনি অন্য ব্যক্তির কণ্ঠ শুনতে পান, সেই ব্যক্তি হয়তো ১০০০ বছর আগে মারা গিয়েছেন। বই-পড়ার মাধ্যমে সময়-ভ্রমণের সুযোগ হয়।
\end{chapquote}

\end{document}
```

Currently, the Bangla texts are not appearing in the `chapquote` environment. Also, there's no option to put a quote source. My desired features for the `chapquote` environment are:

- Allowing to use of both fonts in the quote-text. Activating the English `mytype` font only on the texts that are inside the command `\quotefont{}`. Otherwise, the texts should remain in the default font of the document which was set up in the option of `latexbangla`.
- Keeping the quote-author name in the default font
- Adding an optional argument for showing the quote-source in the next line of quote-author in the default(italic) font. Its alignment should be as same as the quote-author.

Using the above feature, I want to use the environment as something like the following way:

```
আমার পছন্দের একটা উক্তি হলঃ \\
\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}{The source of the quote}              % Quote Source should be optional
    \quotefont{One glance at a book and you hear the voice of another person, perhaps someone dead for 1000 years. To read is to voyage through time.}            
    % The quote texts will be in the quotefont (mytype), but the quote author and source will be in defaut font.
\end{chapquote}
এটার বাংলা অনুবাদ করলে দাঁড়ায় এমনঃ \\
\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
    একটি বইয়ের পাতায় এক নজর তাকালে আপনি অন্য ব্যক্তির কণ্ঠ শুনতে পান, সেই ব্যক্তি হয়তো ১০০০ বছর আগে মারা গিয়েছেন। বই-পড়ার মাধ্যমে সময়-ভ্রমণের সুযোগ হয়।           
     % The quote texts, author and source all will be in defaut font.
\end{chapquote}
```

My desired output is something like: [image: my desired output]

Comment: Comment out the `\uccoff \quotefont` in your environment definition "begin code" part to see the effect of latexbangla, as it handles the transitions. What do you want `quotefont` to do? Latin or Bangla? Or have a `quotefontbangla` if `uccoff`??

Comment: Perhaps a local settransitions command could work - see `ucharclasses` documentation for the syntax.

Comment: I want to use `\quotefont{only english text}` to change the `only english text`  to the font `mytype`. Otherwise the default font of `latexbangla` should be used. And I want to use `\quotefont` anywhere in my document.

Comment: You'll need `{\quotefont only english text}` to restrict the scope of the font if you don't want automatic transitions.

Comment: Using the style file in the question, I am trying to use `{\quotefont only english text}`. I don't understand why it's not working!

Comment: Ohh.. I get it. `{\uccoff \quotefont only english text}` works.

Answer (score 1):

`latexbangla` is using `ucharclasses`'s Unicode block-transitioning mechanism to assign `polyglossia` language environments, which in turn means the chapquote structure ends up with overlapping environments instead of nested environments because `space` counts as part of the latin codeblock. And so, the inevitable error message.

A long-term solution is to slightly decouple `ucharclasses` from the Unicode codeblock definitions by putting space, punctuation and digits into their own (logical) codeblocks.

A short-term workaround is to take over manual control in the chapquote environment and action the `ucharclasses` and `polyglossia` functions separately.

Luckily, there are only two languages/script to consider.

[image: chapquote example]

Here, to visibly highlight what is going on, the Latin quote font is `FreeSerif` in violet, and the Bengali quote font is `Charu_Chandan_3D_Unicode-Regular` in blue.

The `chapquote` environment is modified to have just font commands in the `ucharclasses` transition commands, when going into Latin text and leaving it, and when going into Bangla text. No `polyglossia` environment declarations in the `ucharclasses` commands.

Instead, `\begin{latin}` and `\end{latin}` is manually added around the English quote text.

Outside the `chapquote` environment, the `latexbangla` settings have effect as usual.

MWE

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{test_quote}
%vvvvv
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,   % Kalpurush font: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html 
                banglattfont=Kalpurush,
               ]{latexbangla}
%activate polyglossia
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
%++++++++++++++++++++++
\newfontfamily\qbengalifont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}
\newfontface\bfont{\detokenize{Charu_Chandan_3D_Unicode-Regular}}[Extension=.ttf,
Path=C:/Windows/Fonts/,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
Script=Bengali,
UprightFont=*,
Colour=blue,]
\newfontfamily\qfall{FreeSerif}[Colour=violet]
%\setTransitionsForLatin{\begin{latin}}{\end{latin}}
%\setTransitionsForLatin{}{}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%number all levels
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%     \setotherlanguage{english}

% new font for quotation
\newfontfamily\quotefont[%
    % Scale= 1.1,
    % WordSpace=1.4,
    % AutoFakeSlant=1.2,
    % AutoFakeBold=1.2
    ]{Noto Serif}  % My Type Of Font font: https://www.1001freefonts.com/my-type-of-font.font 

% A chapquote environment for chapter quotes
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
{
\begingroup
\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
    \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
    \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
%    \uccoff \quotefont 
\setTransitionsForLatin{\qfall}{\bfont}
%%\setTransitionsForBengali{\bfont}{\qfall}
\setTransitionTo{Bengali}{\bfont}
%\setTransitionTo{Latin}{\qfall}
}
{\par\medskip\hfill — %\uccoff — \uccon
 \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip
\endgroup}  
\makeatother
%^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\begin{document}

আমার পছন্দের একটা উক্তি হলঃ 
%\uccoff

\bigskip
\bigskip
\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
\begin{latin}
    One glance at a book and you hear the voice of another person, perhaps someone dead for 1000 years. To read is to voyage through time.
\end{latin}
\end{chapquote}
%\uccon

%\vspace{4em}
\bigskip
\bigskip
এটার বাংলা অনুবাদ করলে দাঁড়ায় এমনঃ 

\bigskip
%\uccoff
\begin{chapquote}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
%\setTransitionTo{Bengali}{\qbengalifont}
%\setTransitionTo{BasicLatin}{\qfall}
%\bfont 
    একটি বইয়ের পাতায় এক নজর তাকালে আপনি অন্য ব্যক্তির কণ্ঠ শুনতে পান, সেই ব্যক্তি হয়তো ১০০০ বছর আগে মারা গিয়েছেন। বই-পড়ার মাধ্যমে সময়-ভ্রমণের সুযোগ হয়।
\end{chapquote}
%\uccon

এটার বাংলা অনুবাদ করলে দাঁড়ায় এমনঃ 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
But as I said in my question, I like to keep the quote author in the default font (`latexbangla` setting) and add an optional argument for quote-source (at the next line of the quote author). Can you kindly show these too in your answer?

Comment: I don't fully understand: should there be 4, 6, or 8 components in the environment? Can you do a mock-up or illustration or similar?

Comment: okay, I am going to add my desired output to the question clarification.

Comment: I have updated the question, kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using/correcting the `chapquote` environment, I have obtained the desired output by making two custom commands :

1. `\qtext` command for changing to a different font
2. `\chapquote` command for the quote structure

Here's the MWE:

### test_quote.sty

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,   % Kalpurush font: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html 
                banglattfont=Kalpurush,
               ]{latexbangla}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily\quotefont[%
    % Scale= 1.1,
    % WordSpace=1.4,
    % AutoFakeSlant=1.2,
    % AutoFakeBold=1.2
    ]{[mytype]}  % My Type Of Font font: https://www.1001freefonts.com/my-type-of-font.font     
   
% Command for the different font
\newcommand\qtext[1]{{\normalfont \uccoff \quotefont #1 \uccon}}

% Command for the quote
\NewDocumentCommand\Chapquote{mmO{}}{
        \begin{quotation} 
              \noindent  \itshape{#1} \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip} 
                \begin{flushright} 
                        \textemdash \, \normalfont{#2} \\ \vspace*{-0.1\baselineskip} 
                        \footnotesize\itshape{#3}
                \end{flushright} 
        \end{quotation} }
```

### test_quote.tex

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{test_quote}

\begin{document}

আমার পছন্দের একটা উক্তি হলঃ 
\chapquote{One glance at a book and you hear the voice of another person, perhaps someone dead for 1000 years. \qtext{To read is to voyage through time.}
}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
[The Source of the quote]

এটার বাংলা অনুবাদ করলে দাঁড়ায় এমনঃ 
\chapquote{একটি বইয়ের পাতায় এক নজর তাকালে আপনি অন্য ব্যক্তির কণ্ঠ শুনতে পান, সেই ব্যক্তি হয়তো ১০০০ বছর আগে মারা গিয়েছেন। বই-পড়ার মাধ্যমে সময়-ভ্রমণের সুযোগ হয়।
}{কার্ল সেগান (Carl Sagan)}
% [The Source of the quote]     % as the quote source argument is supposed to be optional 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

And here's the output:
[image: Output of my MWE]

I am quite satisfied with this custom command method and its output. But still, I am looking for help for the question's `chapquote` environment so that it can generate a similar output.