# Configuring custom command for quotes in book class

Tags: macros, xetex, books, quotation, robust-commands

I am trying to configure and optimize my custom [quote commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599796/114006). I like to set it in a way that it will take the quoted text as the mandatory argument and the quote-author and source/description as two optional arguments.

Here's my MWE:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

% \chapquote command for quotes with author or source
\usepackage{xparse}                
\NewDocumentCommand\chapquote{mO{}O{}}{
    \begin{quotation} 
        \noindent  \itshape{#1}
        \IfValueTF {#2}{
            \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip} 
            \begin{flushright} 
                \textemdash \quad \normalfont{#2} \par \footnotesize\itshape{#3}
            \end{flushright}
        }{}
    \end{quotation} 
}                              

% \quote command for quotes with no author or source
\RenewDocumentCommand\quote{m}{
    \begin{quotation} 
        \noindent  \itshape{#1}
    \end{quotation} 
} 

\begin{document}

Example 1. % Quote with both author and source
\chapquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}[Quote Author][Quote Source]

Example 2. % Quote with author only. Here the source line (#3) space should be removed.
\chapquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}[Quote Author][]    

Example 3. % Quote with source only. Here the author line (#2) space should be removed and the emdash should be added to the  source line.    
\chapquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}[][Quote Source]    

Example 4. % Quote without author and source 
\chapquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

Example 5. % Quote without author and source
\quote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

\end{document}
```

I want to set the `\chapquote` such that the quote (`#1`) can be showed only with the source (`#3`), not the author (`#2`). The output of my `Example 3` should be like this:

```
Example 3.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. (#1)
                                          — Quote Source (#3)
```

And I wish to get the same output by `\quote` and `\chapquote` (`Example 4 & 5`) when no optional arguments are specified.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can define `\chapquote` macro like this:

```
\def\chapquote#1{%
   \begin{quotation} 
       \noindent  \itshape{#1}
   \futurelet\next\chapquoteA
}
\def\chapquoteA{\ifx\next[\expandafter\chapquoteB\else\expandafter\chapquoteC\fi}
\def\chapquoteB[#1][#2]{%
   \vskip.2\baselineskip
   \hfill ---\quad 
   \ifx^#1^\else \normalfont #1\par \hfill \fi 
   \footnotesize\itshape #2\par
   \chapquoteC
}
\def\chapquoteC{\end{quotation}}
```

Comment: It's working nicely in my MWE. But it is showing an error `Paragraph ended before \chapquoteB was complete. []` in my [title page](https://github.com/rafisics/ebook-template/blob/master/titlepage.tex#L36) of my main project.

Comment: Maybe, you have more paragraphs in the main {argument} or in the [optional][arguments]. Then you can replace `\def\chapquote#1` by `\long\def\chapquote#1` and  `\def\chapquoteB[#1][#2]` by `\long\def\chapquoteB[#1][#2]`. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/tex-nutshell/tex-nutshell.pdf#cs:long for example.

Comment: I replaced them as you said. But it showing a different error now: `File ended while scanning use of \chapquoteQuote Author]`

Comment: I actually like to use your suggested code in my style file [here](https://github.com/rafisics/ebook-template/blob/8d52389030b1c0fbddb04fd30fe62980dbf3820b/bookstyle.sty#L135-L154).

Comment: Give an example which generates the mentioned error. I am unable to imagine what you are doing.

Comment: I was getting the error because I used your `\chapquote` as `\chapquote{Quote Text}[Quote Author]` instead of `\chapquote{Quote Text}[Quote Author][]`.

Comment: Your solution has solved my problem mostly. Kindly check my `Example 3` in the updated question.

Comment: If you want to process your Example3 then you can try a modification of the macro `\chapquoteB` as shown in my new edit.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted! One issue is I like to remove the extra blank space created at the end while using `\chapquote{Quote Text}[Quote Author][]` on my `Example 2`.

Comment: I'm scratching my head: Where ist the closing "]" to this "[" in your line: `def\chapquoteA{\ifx\next[\expandafter\chapquoteB`... ?

Comment: @KeksDose The `\chapquoteA` macro checks, if the next token in the input queue is `[`. It it is true then it runs `\chapquoteB`. This macro reads the `[` again, then it reads its parameter `#1` and then closing `]`. It reads the second parameter `#2` enclosed in `[...]` too. Then it runs its body.